# the distribution of Martinet

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry

The distribution of Martinet is $\Delta=ker\omega$ with

$\omega=\Bbb dt-\frac{1}{2}y^{2}\Bbb dx$.

let $X=\partial x+\frac{1}{2}y^{2}\partial t$ and $Y=\partial y$

The curvature $2$-forme is: $\Omega=\Bbb d\omega$

so $\Omega=y\Bbb dx \wedge \Bbb dy$

I want to calculate $\Omega(X,Y)=y\Bbb dx \wedge \Bbb dy(X,Y)$.

I know how to calculate it in the Heisenberg case ($4\Bbb dx \wedge \Bbb dy$),  but I don't know how in the  Martinet case because of the unknown $y$.

should I fix the $y$, or is there something else I have to do?

Any help !!

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, you will still have a y variable in the result, but otherwise do the same thing, just treat y in the equation as an unknown number.

If you contract vector fields (which give you vectors depending on the coordinates (x,y,t)) into differential forms (which also can depend on (x,y,t)), there is no reason the result should not depend on the variables.